# AngularFire: signInWithRedirect() and getRedirectResult() not working

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

In my `AuthService` I have a function for signing in with Google which, depending on the user-device, signs the user in with a redirect or a pop-up.

The pop-up sign-in is working without any issues but `signInWithRedirect()` does not seem to work.

```js
public signInWithGoogle() {

  if (this.appService.isMobile) {
    return signInWithRedirect(this.auth, new GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  return signInWithPopup(this.auth, new GoogleAuthProvider()).then(async (userCredentials) => {
    this.user = userCredentials.user;
    this.idToken = await this.user.getIdToken();
    return of(this.user);
  });
}
```

As far as I understood the matter, we're supposed to call `signInWithRedirect()` and then, after the user is returned to our page, use `getRedirectResult()` in order to get the credentials.

However, it keeps returning `null`. I've seen people waiting for the first emit of `onAuthStateChanged()` and call `getRedirectResult()` after the state was emitted the first time but that didn't resolve the issue as well.

I was thinking that this could have something to do with the fact that I am running on `localhost` which does not have a calid SSL certificate - on the other hand `signInWithPopup()` does work so I doubt that this is the problem.

```js
import {
  Auth,
  getRedirectResult,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  idToken,
  signInWithPopup,
  signInWithRedirect,
  user,
  User
} from "@angular/fire/auth";
// ...


@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements OnDestroy {

  private auth: Auth = inject(Auth);
  
  public user$ = user(this.auth);
  
  public idToken$ = idToken(this.auth);
  
  constructor(
    private appService: AppService,
    private logger: NGXLogger,
  ) {
    this.subs.add(this.user$.subscribe(user => this.user = user));
    this.subs.add(this.idToken$.subscribe(idToken => this.idToken = idToken));
  
    this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
      (user) => {
        console.log("onAuthStateChanged");
        console.log(user);
        getRedirectResult(this.auth)
          .then(
            (result) => {
              console.log("redirect result:")
              console.log(result);
            }
          );
      }
    );
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Any chance your browser blocks third-party storage access?

Comment: This is default on Firefox and safari according to the firebase docs I believe.

Comment: @Sergey In [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices) it's stated that "_If you host your app with Firebase Hosting on a subdomain of firebaseapp.com, you are not affected by this issue and no action is needed._". But in my case, of course, the application is running on `localhost`. Should I use an emulator for this? Only had problems with emulators in the past..

Comment: @StefanFalk - any luck with this on localhost?  A similar issue started plaguing me last week when I attempt to sign in with signInWithRedirect on localhost.

Comment: @TryingToLearn I'm afraid not. I think I just started using a dev-environment on firebase in the meantime. However, I recall that there was another issue with Angulars emulators. I don't know if this can be done by now, but you could give those Angular Emulators a shot and see if that works on localhost today.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit

In case is a requirement to run firebase auth in mobile browsers, then we both agree that it's easily predictable that popup auth will not work as we are expecting. So we should decide to try alternative strategies. I would go first trying to implement custom auth strategy, which is documented here: [Custom Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth)

#### Original Answer

According to firebase documentation, in order to use signInWithRedirect, it's necessary:

- setup authDomain in case the app is not hosted on firebase;
- thirdy-party cookies enabled on the browser.

Today chrome is configured by default disabling thirdy-party cookies, so if the final user has an updated browser, the auth process will fail. That's why the you're receiving a null user from `getRedirectResult`, because firebase was unable to retrieve cookie information to exhchange data with google servers to validate authentication.

I suggest you dismiss the `redirect auth strategy`, unless you run your app hosted in a subdomain of firebaseapp.com. Go with the `signinWithPopup` strategy and your changes to succeed will increase.

[Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices#update-authdomain).

The following code demonstrates my code I implemented in an app of mine, which is the following:

```js
  private async updateUser (): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const unsubscribe = this.firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        unsubscribe()
        this.user.set(user)
        resolve()
      },
      reject
      )
    })
  }


  async providerLogin (provider: string): Promise<ProviderLoginDto> {
    let authProvider = null
    switch (provider) {
      case 'facebook':
        authProvider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
        break
      case 'apple':
        authProvider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com')
        break
      case 'google':
      default:
        authProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    }

    try {
      authProvider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account', scope: 'openid profile email' })
      const userCredentials = await this.firebaseApp.auth().signInWithPopup(authProvider)
      if (userCredentials && userCredentials.user) {
        await this.updateUser()
        if (this.user.isLoggedIn()) {
          return {
            email: this.user.firebaseUser?.email || undefined,
            provider: provider,
            id: this.user.firebaseUser?.uid,
            success: true,
            error: undefined
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        const firebaseError = error as firebase.FirebaseError
        if (firebaseError) {
          // throw new AuthProviderError(getTranslation(firebaseError.code, firebaseError.message), error)
        }
      }
      throw error
    }
    return {
      success: false
    }
  }
```

Comment: I wouldn't mind, but on mobile devices the pop-up is being blocked. Afaik it is recommnded to use the redirect-method for mobile devices?

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of that. I think I'll have to go the Custom Auth route in this case.

Comment: It turns out the Custom Auth is not really the best option here. As stated in the docs, [The redirect method is preferred on mobile devices.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin) which means the redirect-method should actually work on mobile devides.